# Why is child element not fitting inside parent element (resulting in scroll bars)?

Tags: html, css

I have a child element, that is not fitting inside the parent element (by what looks like 1px), resulting in vertical scroll bars. The problem only occures in old versions of Windows / Internet Explorer. I think it was Windows 7.

More detail: the `<label for="toggle">Menu</label>` is the element with the scroll bars as it appears to not fit within the `<header>`. But the height of the `header` is determined by the `label`, so I don't understand why this is.

JS Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/a9zkgyx7/

```
<header>
    <div class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="resources/logo.svg"></a></div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
    <label for="toggle">Menu</label>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="link.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">Text</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">Text</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
</header>





 article, aside, figure, footer, header, main, nav, section {
        display: block;
        }

header { 
    padding:0 3.6rem;
    border-bottom:1px solid;
    overflow:auto;
    }

.logo {
    float:left;
    width:13.2rem;
    }

#toggle {
    display: none;
    }

#toggle ~ label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    float:right;
    font-size:2.4rem;
    line-height:7.1rem;
    }


nav {
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:7.2rem;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    z-index:102;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:4.8rem;
    line-height:1.75em;
    }

#toggle:checked ~ nav {
    height: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: you can hide your scrollbar with this `overflow-y: hidden;`

Comment: OK, but I would rather not have the scrollbar in the first place.

Comment: How old are we talking about? Is this a version of IE that doesn't recognise elements like `header` and `nav` as blocks? If so, install the HTML5shim.

Comment: I think it was Windows 7 that I noticed the issue. My CSS contains the following code: header, nav { display: block; }. I thought that should do the trick for older browsers that don't support HTML5?

Comment: Could it be that the browser is so old that it needs a vendor prefix for `float`? Generally if something is not working on only one browser (especially IE), running your code through an auto-prefixer is always worth a try.

Comment: @xmastertje overflow: hidden would stop old IE from displaying scrollbars and  the <header> keeps its height (I thought if I removed overflow:auto it would shrink to 0 height).

Comment: @Markeee yes haha do you want me to put that as an answer?

Comment: @xmastertje possibly a correct answer, but I'd want to do research on any repurcussions for changing overflow from auto to hidden. I need the element to maintain its height, even though the children are floated.

Comment: @Markeee I understand. I will just put is as an answer and you can accept it if you want to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css header you have to change `overflow:auto;` to `overflow:hidden;` this will hide your scrollbar.